# Connecting to MYSQL Remotely

Tags: c#, mysql, database, ip

When i hardcode the ip address in connectionstring for mysql, client system successfully gets data from database from host system(ip). But when i try to connect to the same by getting the ip address from a txt doc in clientsystem, it is unable to connect to my host database. But the same code(retriving ip from a txt doc) works in host system. Why is it not working in client system? I used the following code, Can Anyone Help me in finding what is wrong?

```
    namespace ThermalDotNet
    {
    public partial class ipcheck : Form
    {
    public ipcheck()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        labelget();
        myconnectionstring = "Server='" + localhost + "';port = 3306; Database=" + database + "; Uid=root; Pwd=fatehshah; Allow Zero DateTime = True";
    }
   // string constr = "Server=192.168.1.102; Database=mydb; Uid=myusername; Pwd=mypassword; Allow Zero DateTime = True";
    string localhost = null;
    string str;
    string database = null;
    string[] strarray;
    string myconnectionstring = null;

    public void labelget()
    {

        try
        {
            // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file. 
            // The using statement also closes the StreamReader. 
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:/Requirement.txt"))
            {

                while ((str = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    str = sr.ReadLine();
                    strarray = str.Split(',');
                    localhost = strarray[0];
                    database = strarray[1];
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ea)
        {
            // Let the user know what went wrong.
            MessageBox.Show("error is " + ea);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
    private void ipcheck_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(myconnectionstring);
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT CAT_NAME FROM CATEGORY WHERE CAT_ID = '1'", con);
        MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (r.Read())
        {
            label1.Text = r["CAT_NAME"].ToString();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of `localhost` is what you expect it to be after reading from the file?

Comment: Is there a newline at the end of the text file? If so, it may be reading the second line (which is probably "") and then splitting it to get a single-valued array comprised on an empty string.

Comment: @stalerster, I checked that part and It works in host system. and i took the exe of t and installed in client system. but there it did not work.

Comment: No @Ceisc.I just copied the same text doc there in client system which i used on host system

Comment: Do you realise that you're calling ReadLine() twice? This may cause you not to have the values you were expecting (but doesn't explain differing behaviour between two systems, assuming all else is equal).

Comment: Yae @Ceisc.But I am just assigning str to it. and it is not cause for any problem, as it is working fine in host system

Comment: @Ameena: Yes, you are assigning str to it in the statement, but in the next line you overwrite str with a second sr.ReadLine(). meaning you effectively skip certain lines in your file (1, 3, 5...). Have your catch clause print out the value of your database string to be sure the value is correct.

Comment: There are 2 small problems in your code... 1. You are reading the line at least twice. 2. Although it doesn't throw an exception, and the StreamReader accepts it, the path to the file is wrong, it should be "C:\Requirement.txt" and you should escape the "\" character... Also you are not respecting any C# coding style... :-<

Comment: @darkArk,Ceisc. Thank You So much for pointing it out. Yes, reading line twice was my problem.